# Ordering autocompletion hints in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need help with this:

I have autocompletion set so it pops up after every key being pressed. The problem is with ordering of hints, I would realy need the keywords, being first in the list. How can I do that?

There is one another related issue for example I write final keyword, and it is not first in the list, so I have to press Esc, is there any way to insert completely matched word without ending up with 30 letters long fully classified class name in place of the intended one?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse preferences give you limited control over this behavior. What you can modify via the UI can be found under the preferences at Java/Editor/Content Assist, and Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced.

Comment: And also Java / Edit / Templates to create your own proposals